# Python 3.7.3 Inconsistent code for song guessing code, stops working at random times

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python code that is a song guessing game, you are given the artist and the songs first letter, I used 2 2d arrays with on being the artist and the other being the song. I know I should've done a 3d array though to change it this late into my code I'd have to restructure the whole code and I wouldn't have time. Here is the appropriate code below:

```
                    attemptnum = 5                

                    attempts = 0               
                    for x in range (10):
                        ArtCount = len(artist)
                        print(ArtCount)
                        randNum = int(random.randint(0, ArtCount))
                        randArt = artist[randNum]
                        ArtInd = artist.index(randArt)# catches element position (number)
                        songSel = songs[randNum]
                        print ("The artist is " + randArt)
                        time.sleep(1)

                        print( "The songs first letter be " + songSel[0])
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print("")
                        question = input("What song do you believe it to be? ")
                        if question == (songSel) or ("c"):
                            songs.remove(songSel)
                            artist.remove(randArt)
                            print ("Correct")
                            print ("Next Question")







                        else:
                            attempts = attempts + 1
                            att = attemptnum = attemptnum - attempts
                            print("")
                            print("Wrong,")
                            print (att) and print (" attempts left.")
                            print("")
                            time.sleep(0.5)

                            if attempts == 5:
                                print("GAME OVER")
                                #input leaderboard here
                                print("Exiting in 3 seconds")
                                time.sleep(3)
                                exit()
```

Apologies if my code isn't so polished, this is a project for school. So what this code does is randomly a number from 0 to the number of how many elements the artist's list has. It then chooses an artist using the random number, it catches the number used with index so that it can be used on the songs array to get the corresponding song (I know very bad) It pitches the question and shows the first letter of the song. If you get the song you get the same code again but with the prior song and artist removed to prevent dupes. That's where the problem comes in, when usually running the code it'll randomly give me the error where the element I'm trying to output is not in the list:

```
                    randArt = artist[randNum]
                    IndexError: list index out of range
```

This can happen anywhere throughout the code when you're being asked a question, you can get to question 3 and get the error, or not even get to question 9 and get the error. It's completely random. I feel like its trying to occasionally get a hold of an artist and song that's been removed but that doesn't make sense since it only chooses from the amount counted on the list, not the original 10. I'm not sure if my way of saying it is right or if any one would understand, because I sure don't. To clarify, my code counts how many elements there are in the list, uses that number to find a song and artist, then removes it after to stop duping, but from what I can see it seems like it's trying to find and element simply out of the range of how many elements there actually are. Thanks for bearing with my amateur code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`random.randint` is inclusive in both ends. `randint(0, 10)` will return a number in the range

`0 <= _ <= 10`.

However Python uses 0-based indexes.

If `li` is `[1, 2, 3]` then `len(li)` is 3, but `li[3]` does not exist.

Only `li[0]`, `li[1]` and `li[2]` do.

---

When you are doing

```
ArtCount = len(artist)
randNum = int(random.randint(0, ArtCount))
randArt = artist[randNum]
```

You are asking for a number in the range `0 <= n <= len(artist)`. If `n == len(artist)` then `artist[n]` will cause an `IndexError`.

BTW, `randint` returns an `int` (hence the `int` in its name). `int(randint(...))` is totally unnecessary.

You should either ask for a random number in the range `0 <= n <= len(artist) - 1` or simply use `random.choice`:

```
randArt = random.choice(artist)
```

You may want to catch an `IndexError` just in case `artist` is an empty list:

```
try:
    randArt = random.choice(artist)
except IndexError:
    print('artist list is empty')
```

Comment: Exactly! Also there is the condition missing in case the list of songs is empty.

Comment: You genuinely solved 5 days of confusion with 2 characters. I put - 1 on the art count and it worked like a charm. Thank you very much, the code will be done in no time.